# To give a message regarding the users input in html textarea in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a user put input in  tag and want to give him a message when he/she clicks the submit button that whether his/her input was right or wrong using jQuery/javascript.

eg: i ask them to write  in the textarea and if their input is what i asked the answer should be success else failed, using jQuery/javascript.

Javascript beginner.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have some html/form structure? If possible, please make fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/, with code you have so far.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? We need a little bit more context of what you're building.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sample can get you going:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="button" />
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    var textarea = $('#textarea');
    $('#submit').on('click', function (event) {
        var value = textarea.val();
        event.preventDefault();
        if (value === 'value you want it to be') {
            alert('yes');
        } else {
            alert('no');
        }
    });
}());
```

Of course you haven't given a lot of details but maybe this can get you started?

Answer (score 0):

If you want check whether a user fill a field:
html:

```
<form action="#">
    <input id="firstName" name="" type="text">
    <input id="lastName" name="" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub"></form>
</form>
```

---

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit',function(){
        $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
            var long=$(this).val().length
            if(long==0){
                var id=$(this).attr('id')
                alert('you must fill the '+id+' field')
                }
            })
        })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" value="some text">
<p></p>

<script>
$( "input" ).keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    if (value === 'value you want it to be') {
        $( "p" ).text("Correct");
    } else {
        $( "p" ).text("Wrong");
    }
  })
  .keyup();
</script>
```